# RabbitMQ message lost

Tags: python, go, rabbitmq

I use Python api to insert message into the RabbitMQ,and then use go api to get message from the RabbitMQ.

**Key 1**: RabbitMQ ACK is set false because of performance.

I insert into RabbitMQ about over 100,000,000 message by python api,but when I use go api to  get
message,I find the insert number of message isn’t equal to the get number.The insert action and the

get action are concurrent.

**Key 2**:Lost message rate isn’t over 1,000,000 percent 1.

Insert action has log,python api shows that all inserted message is successful.

Get action has log,go api shows that all get message is successful.
But the number isn’t equal.

**Question1**:I don’t know how to find the place where the message lost.Could anyone give me a suggestion how to find where the message lost?

**Question2**:Is there any strategy to insure the message not lose?

Comment: I fix it,it is my first time to ask question.And I hope that I have described the question clearly.

Comment: Are you sending all your message to the same queue/routing_key?

Comment: yes we are.Finally we found it was caused by the publisher because of timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to test that all of your messages are published you may do it this way:

1. Stop consumer.
2. Enable acknowledgements in publisher. In python you can do it by adding extra line to your code: `channel.confirm_delivery()`. This will basically return a boolean if message was published. Optionally you may want to use `mandatory` flag in `basic_publish`.
3. Send as many messages as you want.
4. Make sure that all of the `basic_publish()` methods returnes True.
5. Count number of messages in Rabbit.
6. Enable Ack in consumer by doing `no_ack = False`
7. Consume all the messages.

This will give you an idea where your messages are getting lost.

Comment: step 1:test publiser.
step 2:test consumer.
All the 2 has connection to RabbitMQ,it's a good idea.
But the system is online,I can't make the consumer or the publisher stop.
I can only find the problem in the online context.
Do rabbitmq has message count mechanism when it is running?I am not much familiar to rabbitmq.Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at management plugin this will allow you to check messages in "real-time".  Also in your case you may create a test queue. bind it to the same routing key that the original (production) has. Then all the messages will be duplicated into both queues. Then you can play with the test queue.